# Symfony2.7 Twig How to obtain a token?

Tags: symfony, twig, token

Inside Twig file I have this code:

```
{% set player = app.security.getToken().getUser().getPlayer() %}

{% if player.getSelectedCharacter() is not null %}
    {% set character = player.getSelectedCharacter() %}
    {% .... %}
{% endif %}
```

But at now, `app.security` is deprecated. So I want to change this. I can obtain user token inside my controller and send it to the Twig. But I prefer to get it directly via Twig.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said and mentioned in the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/twig_reference.html#app).

> The app.security global is deprecated as of 2.6. The user is already
>   available as app.user and is_granted() is registered as function.

I think you can just try something like this in your view.

```
app.user.getPlayer()
```